# Do I use $? correctly?

Tags: bash

I want to verify if I can connect to a database (PostgresSQL) into a bash script

I execute the following command (PGUSER, PGDATABASE...  are set)

```
 psql -f sql/test_connection.sql > /dev/null 2>&1
```

When I echo `$?` it shows 0 if success, 2 if not.

It works fine in a terminal.

When I put it into a bash script the result is always 0 even when the credentials are not correct.

```
psql -f sql/test_connection.sql > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? ]
then
   echo "OK"
else
   echo "Doudh!!"
fi
```

Where am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if you just pass `$?` to [`test`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/test1.html) (another name for `[`), that will expand to the string `0` or `2` depending on whether the command was successful. When `test` is passed a string it just tests if the string is non-empty. In this case, it will always return `0` (true), as both of those strings are non-empty.

What you probably want to do is just use the return value of `psql` as the argument to `if` directly, without having to refer to it using `$?`:

```
if psql -f sql/test_connection.sql > /dev/null 2>&1
then
   echo "OK"
else
   echo "Doudh!!"
fi
```

Or, you could test `$?` against `0` directly

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "OK"
else
   echo "Doudh!!"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

When running the script use the `-x` option which prints out each command being executed with actual values. Its very useful for debugging. You'll get to see what is compared with what, what is passed to which command.

```
$sh -x prg.sh
```

or

```
$bash -x prg.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to think in bash and in not C, java, perl... with kind of `if true`

Answer (score 1):

`[ $? ]` is equivalent to `[ -n $? ]` which will check whether the expansion of `$?` is a string of nonzero length, which will always be true since `$?` expands to an exit status which will never be the empty string.  In order to check whether a value is zero or not use `[$? -eq 0]` or `(( $? ))`.

It is besides better to use:

```
if psql -f sql/test_connection.sql > /dev/null 2>&1
then
   echo "OK"
else
   echo "Doudh!!"
fi
```

Which will run the command and execute the then part if the exit status of the command is zero or the else part if it is nonzero.